# How to sync content between two Mediawiki installations?

Tags: mediawiki, synchronization

Is there a reliable way to sync (copy and merge) the content of two different Mediawiki installations?

I have an internal installation where we work on most the time, but some external contractors won't get access to the internal installation, so we are thinking about getting them their own installation and mirror parts of the content to that installation. Problem is, doing this manually will be a pain, so I'm looking for a way to automate this procedure.

Sync should be in both directions, as both parties can create and update content.

I hoped there would be an extension for that, but couldn't find one yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem and am looking for a solution.  I found an extension called Push that may work: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Push but have not had time to test it yet.

Answer (score 2):

This question is super old, but just wanted to say here is the collection of extensions that would be relevant here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Page_import

- PushAll is an updated version of push: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PushAll
- Page Exchange is for specific packages of pages: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Exchange
- PageSync is for synchronizing using something like git - https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageSync
- Sync sounds like what OP is asking for, but last update was 2018 - https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Sync

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found an additional possible solution:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiSync